# Using Walker To Add Menu CSS Class Functionality

Tags: menus

I'm trying to add the ability to insert Custom CSS Classes to menu items. I believe I do this by extending the walker_nav_menu but I'm not sure how to call the custom classes.

This seems like such a simple question but I've googled and searched here and couldn't find anything for simply adding the custom classes.

Right now I just have:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'top-menu', 'walker' => new future_walker_class() ) ); ?>
```

and

```
class future_walker_class extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
/*not sure what to put here*/
}
```

P.S. I'm fairly new to PHP/Wordpress. I tried to be as thorough as possible so I don't waste your time.

Comment: Can you please let us know exactly what is the need of adding custom css classes and do you need to add the same class to each menu items ? or do you want different classes based on any condition to menu item, sub menu items etc ?

Comment: I'd like to give the menu item an icon from an image sprite using css. So the classes need to be different (based on input from the Menu admin panel).

Comment: I know it automatically generates one like `.item804` but in case I move them around (and there's quite a few of them) I want the css code to be easy to read and edit if needed.

Answer (score 1):

If its a matter of adding icons as per the classes, add it from the back-end and use that class to assign icons through css.

[image]

Comment: Yep I've done just that. But the custom class doesn't print to html. So I figured that I had to call it somehow using the walker class.

Comment: Do you have any code that renders the menu structure ? or Can you tell me the name of the Theme you are using ?

Comment: Sorry for delay... I tried doing some digging myself. I rephrased the question with more info that I got from my digging: [new question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130236/getting-stripos-error-when-trying-to-add-menu-classes)

Answer (score 0):

okay so based on your code it looks to me like you are working with a child theme, or maybe your own theme. -- this answer is based on that assumption.

First things first, you need to register your (new) menu.

```
// -- This will go in functions.php
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'menu-1' => __( 'Menu 1' ),
      'menu-2' => __( 'Menu 2' ),
      'menu-3' => __( 'Menu 3' )
    )
  );
}
```

You will then need to assign location to the menu in `wp-admin > appearance > menus`

Then you can style the custom walker

```
// functions.php
class your_new_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
   function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = Array()) {
        $output .= '<ul class="sub-menu">';
    }
        function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = Array()) {
        $output .= '</ul>';
    }
}
```

then when you are ready to call the new menu lets say in `header.php`

```
<!-- header.php -- assuming php is closed at this point -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
        'theme_location'  => 'menu-1',
   //   'items_wrap'      => 'nav-wrap', un comment if you want 
        'container_class' => 'class1 class2',
        'walker'          => new your_new_Walker_Nav_Menu
    ));
    ?>
    </div>
```